# set the day of week with javascript, html

Tags: javascript, html

I’m working on course registration page. I’d like to set a start date and end date with the day of week. For example, one class starts from 10/5 to 10/31 every Monday.
Another class start from 10/5 to 10/31 every Tuesday and Thursday. I'd like add picking the day of week in below code. How could I set the day of week?

```
<label for ="startdate">Start date
<input type="date" id="startdate"">
<label for ="enddate">End date
<input type="date" id="enddate"">
```

please let me know. Thanks :)

Comment: Just use a <select> with an <option> for each weekday? Is this for filtering the classes? Because shouldn't people pick the class instead?

Comment: what does starts from 10/5 to 10/31 every monday mean, it makes no sense

Comment: @BryanDellinger It means the Monday class is on Monday, October 5th, Monday, October 12th, and so on

Comment: you'd need to create your own date picker, or use a library that has that functionality